# C++ undefined reference to `utils::checkInputs

Tags: c++, string, header-files, cout

I decided to try and code a basic program but i keep getting this eror:

/tmp/cczXwiYT.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to`utils::checkInputs(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Im new to c++ (just saying)

I tried to change the type from void to int to boolean etc.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "utils.h"

int main(){

    utils u;

    std::string a = "a";
    std::string b = "a";
    u.checkInputs(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

utils.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include "utils.h"

using namespace std;

utils::utils(){};

void checkInputs(string userInput, string target){
    cout << "hey i work" << endl;
}
```

utils.h

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

class utils
{
    public:
        utils();
        void checkInputs(string userInput, string target);
};

#endif
```

Thanks for the help =)

Comment: Typo: change `void checkInputs...` to `void utils::checkInputs...` in utils.cpp.

Comment: And `please` ditch the `using namespace std;` line.

Comment: @Chimera: The one in the `.h`, right?  (While we’re at it, please name C++ header files `.hpp`, `.hxx`, or `.hh`.)

Comment: @DavisHerring Now you have the hang of it! :-)

Comment: Sanders thank you I will try that

Comment: @chimera ok..why so does it affect the code in some way

Comment: @Petereo No, it doesn't. It's just considered by some to be lazy. It's just a style or "best practice" consideration that not everybody will agree with. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone as said by PaulSanders "Typo: change void checkInputs... to void utils::checkInputs... in utils.cpp." It fixed my problem just fine =)